# Process not showing under ps -ef | grep command

Tags: shell-script, process, fifo

I ran a command in shell
`cat >my1.fifo &`
and when trying to find the PID it is not showing under

```
ps -ef | grep my1.fifo
```

Answer (score 1):

The redirection is done by the shell before executing `cat`.  It's a bit like this:

```
(
    exec >my1.fifo
    exec cat
) &
```

As you can see, `cat` is run with no command-line arguments, but with its standard out connected to the open file.  It has almost no knowledge of what it's writing to (certainly it doesn't know the file's name(s)).

Answer (score 0):

You will not find pid for `cat` if you run it like this:

```
cat >my1.fifo &
```

The reason is simple: `cat` supposed to read from its stdin and finish, once the stdin is closed. The push of the command to background (`&` at the end) closes stdin of the starting process.

In other words, the command `cat >my1.fifo &` goes into background, and immediately completes. So subsequent `ps` will not find it - nothing to find.

If you want to know what was the pid of that process, do `echo $!` - it will print the pid of the last process sent to background. And of course, you will not find this pid in the list of processes anymore (it finished).

But if you'll will use something else, for example `tail -f somefile >my1.fifo &`, then you will find that `tail` in the list of processes and `echo $!` will show its pid.

Comment: That last isn't true if we're still searching for `my1.fifo` in the process arguments.

Comment: What shell are you using, White Owl?  In Bash, `cat >/dev/null &` results in a process that's stopped (`SIGTTIN`) until foregrounded - still connected to the parent's input stream.